# php add class to every item in while loop except the 1st item

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do I add a class to every item in while loop instead of the 1st item? I want to do something that affects every element in the loop except the 1st element. For example adding class `someClass` to 
`<div class="items"></div>` to every element in the loop except the 1st element. How can I do this?

Example code:

```
<?php while($a = $abc->fetch()){ extract($a); ?>
    <div class="items"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @iainn I want to add class to every item except the fist and not to even and odds.

Comment: Sorry, completely misread that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php while($a = $abc->fetch()){ extract($a); ?>
    <div class="<?php if($i++ != 0) echo "items";?>"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a boolean on the first iteration, then make a conditional based on how you want to process:

```
$first = true;
while (...) {
    if ($first) {
        // only fires on the first line
        $first = false;
    } else {
        // fires for every line but the first
    }
    // fires on every line
}
```